# undefined variable-markers show no error in coding

Tags: php, variables, undefined

This is my 1st time posting on this site, and coming to an end in my PHP class. Looking through Stack and as well as some script validators I am not seeing any errors, however when I am going to my login view page it is giving me an Undefined Variable in line 3

```
<?php if( $bad_login ) : ?>
```

Login.php = just source coding

```
<?php

$bad_login = false;

if ( isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){

if( $_POST['username'] == 'admin' && $_POST['password'] == 'password' ){

} else {    
    $bad_login = true;
}

}

 require( "showbooks.php" );

?>
```

login.view.php simple login form (Should pop login error msg or success(which is where my problem is))

```
<h1>Please Login In</h1>

<?php if( $bad_login ) : ?>
 <p>Username and Password combination is Invalid.</p>
<?php endif ?>

<form action="login.view.php<?php  ?>" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

<p>
<label for="username">Username: </label><input type ="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
</p>

<p>
<label for="password">Password: </label><input type ="password"  name="password"  value="" id="password">

</p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Confused as to what your setup is, is login.php being included in login.view.php? Where is $bad_login supposed to be set within login.view.php?

Comment: login.php is running in the background, where as login.view.php is the only view-able screen Displaying only the "Please Login" along with the form. The setup is that only the form will be seen, to where you are able to login, if it fails it is supposed to give the error message and vice versa.              $bad_login is suppose to be defined by the user's input whether the input was correct or not. UN:"admin" pw:"password". However just refreshing the page shows the 'undefined variable' in line 3 on the page.

Comment: In this case, login.view.php can not know any information about `$bad_login`. You sould check credentials before displaying the form. For example, move you validations from `login.php` to `login.view.php`. Or you can include `login.php` from `login.view.php` (but consider removing  `require( "showbooks.php" );`). Or include `login.view.php` from `login.php`

Comment: I tried `required('login.php')` on the `login.view.php` to have it pull the code, and that seemed to work for connecting the two, now I will get to play with the rest and see if how that goes. Do you think it could lead to any problems down the road going this route? and thanks -rNix for pointing that out for me (That it wasn't connecting).

Comment: Your `login.php` does the validation, but also contains `require( "showbooks.php" );` which does not correlate with name of the file.

Comment: Yeah, sorry forgot to add that that is another part of the program I am writing. Making a full out library database mixed with the CRUD system. So that is more so for redirection / information for admin only purposes.

Comment: Actually looking at it again, it cleaned up my program removing it, and it works fine. Thanks for the insight.